# p element inside div is wider than the parent div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Take a look at the link. The p element within it's parent has more width. I want to display p within the dialog box. How would I do this?

http://jsfiddle.net/2y1wj0mm/

```
.dialog-box {
margin:0 auto;
width:300px;
height:200px;
background-color:#326A16;
-webkit-filter:drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px #000000);
border-radius:20%/34%;
}
.dialog-box:before {
content:"";
position: absolute;
width: 0px;
height: 0px;
border-right: 21px solid transparent;
border-left: 18px solid transparent;
border-top: 42px solid #326A16;
margin:195.71428571428572px 90px;
}
.dialog-box p {
display:inline;
margin:10% 14%;
text-wrap:normal;
}
```

Comment: what happen to your `margin:195.71428571428572px` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update your `.dialog-box`:

```
.dialog-box p {
    display: block;
    margin:10% 14%;
    width: 200px;
    word-wrap: wrap;
    word-break: break-all;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
```

3 things to do here:

1. `display: inline` does not work in your case; you have to use the width & height of `p` element
2. You have to wrap & break the words using `word-wrap` and `word-break`
3. You probably need to place the words inside the green dialog, using `padding-top`

Side note:

There is no point to set margin with so many decimal places. Use integers only.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9bpyjnfL/1/

Comment: maybe using ```overflow-wrap: normal``` instead of ```word-wrap: wrap;```
since according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap) the first one is the original one and the second just an alias that might be deprecated in the future

Answer (score 2):

It happens because you put text without any whitespaces in it, so browser is not sure how to break those long line. You can instruct it with `word-wrap` property:

```
.dialog-box {
    /* ... */
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/2y1wj0mm/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this i change `p` to `block` element and gave it a width

```css
.dialog-box {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#326A16;
    -webkit-filter:drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px #000000);
    border-radius:20%/34%;
}
.dialog-box:before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-right: 21px solid transparent;
    border-left: 18px solid transparent;
    border-top: 42px solid #326A16;
    margin:195.71428571428572px 90px;
}
.dialog-box p {
    display:inline-block;
    width:260px;
    margin:20px;
    
    text-wrap:normal;
    word-break:break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="dialog-box">
    <p>hi there?kjhkjhkgygyfyjfffhjvhvvjhjassasasasa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa c c vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2y1wj0mm/3/)**

CSS:

```
.dialog-box p {
    display:block;
    margin:10% 14%;
    width:80%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.dialog-box p {
    display: block;
    height: 180px;
    margin: 10% 14%;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
dialog-box p {
margin: 10% 10%;
padding: 13px 0px 0px 0px;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JSFIDDLe

http://jsfiddle.net/2y1wj0mm/4/

```
.dialog-box p {
 //you can use inline-block also but you need to adjust the margin and padding
    display:block;
    margin:10%;
    width:80%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    padding:5%;
}
```

BY default p is a Block level element. so default css will be applied here
So you cannot use as inline element